# Get indexpath outside of any tableView function

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, nsindexpath

Maybe my question is very simple and I am just too stupid to get it.
My problem is that I want to access the indexPath outside of

```
overide func tableView(...)
```

So I am in my TableView Class and have a separate class like:

```
func setColor()
{
...
}
```

Inside this class I want to access the indexPath. How can I do this?

Comment: Pass the indexPath as a parameter.

Comment: You need to clarify what your goal is. How and when is this `setColor` method being called? What class is it in?

Comment: I am in class TableView, outside from another class I call this function, named setColor.

Comment: So, some other class calls `setColor`. What does `setColor` need the index path for? What it is setting the color of?

Comment: I want to call this class when the selection of the tableView moves to an other cell. I can't do this with didSelecrRowAtIndexPath due sometimes the cell color should change although if the user doesn't tap at the cell, like a segue.

Comment: It sets the background color for the cell according to the current view the user is in like a navigation, I need the index path to change the background color for the cell, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexPath is an object, which is created and passed to the UITabelViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource methods. It lets you indicate which cell is loaded/tapped etc.

So you will not be able to access this object from outside. If you want to change something of a cell e.g. the backgroundColor you should store the color in a property, change this property and force a redraw. In the delegate method, which creates the cells use this property to set the color.

Here is some sample code.

**ViewController**

```
class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Store array of color
    var backColors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]


    // Method which changes color
    func setColor(row: Int, color: UIColor) {
        backColors[row] = color
    }

    // Override draw
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create your cell
        // ...

        // Set color
        cell.backgroundColor = backColors[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to change the background color of the cell. So I should force to reload the tableView and then inside the cellforRowAtIndexPath I should then set the color?

Comment: This is how i would do this. Store the color in your controller, force a redraw and inside cellforRowAtIndexPath method use this color.